# passing functions as arguments in other functions python

Tags: python, function

I have these functions, and I'm getting errors, with the do_twice functions, but I'm having problems debugging it

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#functins exercise 3.4

def do_twice(f):
    f()
    f()

def do_four(f):
    do_twice(f)
    do_twice(f)

def print_twice(str):
    print str + 'one' 
    print str + 'two'


str = 'spam'
do_four(print_twice(str))
```

debugger errors

```
:!python 'workspace/python/functions3.4.py'
spamone
spamtwo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workspace/python/functions3.4.py", line 18, in <module>
    do_four(print_twice(str))
  File "workspace/python/functions3.4.py", line 9, in do_four
    do_twice(f)
  File "workspace/python/functions3.4.py", line 5, in do_twice
    f()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

shell returned 1
```

Comment: As a side note, it's a bad idea to call a variable `str`; that's the name of one of the most important built-in types in Python, and the function you use to get the friendly representation of any object, so you don't want to hide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `do_four(print_twice(str))` evaluates the expression in the brackets first before passing it. Since print_twice doesn't return anything, `None` is assumed, and that gets passed.

Comment: oh, yes... now I see it. instead of passing the function I'm just getting its return back.. in other words, to get something from my function call I would have to add a return statement in my print_twice functions

Comment: Or pass the function and the argument through, which is what partial (below) effectively does.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the expression `print_twice(str)` is evaluated by calling `print_twice` with `str` and getting the result that you returned,* and that result is what you're passing as the argument to `do_four`.

What you need to pass to `do_four` is a function that, when called, calls `print_twice(str)`.

You can build such a function manually:

```
def print_twice_str():
    print_twice(str)
do_four(print_twice_str)
```

Or you can do the same thing inline:

```
do_four(lambda: print_twice(str))
```

Or you can use the higher-order function [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to do it for you:

```
from functools import partial
do_four(partial(print_twice, str))
```

The documentation for `partial` has a pretty nice explanation:

> The `partial()` is used for partial function application which “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature. For example, `partial()` can be used to create a callable that behaves like the `int()` function where the *base* argument defaults to two: [snip] `basetwo = partial(int, base=2)`

---

<sub>* If you're thinking "But I didn't return anything, so where does that `None` come from?": Every function always returns a value in Python. If you don't tell it what to return, it returns `None`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Right now `print_twice` is returning `None` which is what ends up being passed to `do_four` as a parameter. In other words, you are passing the result of the function call instead of the function call itself.

Instead you want to wrap that function call in a lamda function like this:

```
do_four(lambda: print_twice(str))
```

This will pass the actual function call as a parameter instead of calling the function and passing its result.